# How to enable error messages from `prove`?

Tags: perl, perl-prove

This is the simple perl test which has syntax errors:

```
$ echo 'foo+' > t1.t
$ perl t1.t
syntax error at t1.t line 1, at EOF
Execution of t1.t aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Is there a way to provide some option to `prove` utility to see that error message? Currently if I run that test with prove I can not understand what is wrong with it:

```
$ prove -v t1.t
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
No subtests run 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t1.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=1, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.01 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

In my case `t1.t` test is much complex (I can not pastebin its code) and I can run it directly with `perl` without any problem, but I can not run it by `prove`. Because of errors like above. So I am trying to find a way to see actual reason of failing test.

**UPD**
Detailed debug information: https://pastebin.com/gqMbdTb8

Comment: What is the output of `prove -I. -Ilocal/lib/perl5 t/*.t` ? No need to run `perl /usr/bin/prove` but `prove` alone

Comment: Are you asking how to debug a program non-interactively? Use output statements (e.g. `diag`) to trace the progress of the program and to examine values.

Comment: @ikegami: I remade my question.

Comment: [But it does show the message.](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/064ab5b4bd51a675548d26797ab06fe1) ([In colour.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n52l.png)) Always has. (Well, at least as far back as 2006 / Perl 5.8.9 with Test-Harness 2.64.)

Comment: @ikegami: strange, very strange. My colored version: https://imgur.com/a/aTkwY3k What is your version of utilities?

Comment: All of them. (2.64 [released with 5.8.9], 3.44 [latest, and released with 5.36], and some in between)

Comment: I get the same results as @ikegami.

Comment: @ikegami, I will investigate into this problem. Seems like my environment is guilty then.

Comment: @tobyink: I will investigate into this problem. Seems like my environment is guilty then.

Comment: @ikegami: While debugging found this ENV variable: `PERL_TEST_HARNESS_DUMP_TAP` https://perldoc.perl.org/TAP::Harness#Instance-Methods .Setting it to `TAP` allows to see the output from tests in corresponding files. Does your environment specifies STDOUT in some way via that variable? (Please reopen the question, because I found the answer)

Comment: @tobyink: Added debug information and possible answer. Please review.

Comment: is_test and is_bailout should be false. (is_unknown is true)

Comment: Formatter/Console/ParallelSession.pm? I think the use of this module might be the difference. I think it's used when a value greater than one is provided for the `jobs` parameter. Is `prove` an alias?

Comment: @ikegami: No, it seems regular command: `$ which prove
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.3/bin/prove`

Answer (score 0):

While debugging I found [this](https://perldoc.perl.org/TAP::Harness#Instance-Methods) environment variable `PERL_TEST_HARNESS_DUMP_TAP`. We can set it to some directory name and see a result of testing.

```
$ echo 'foo+' > t1.t

$ PERL_TEST_HARNESS_DUMP_TAP=output perl t1.t
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
No subtests run 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t1.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=1, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.01 CPU)
Result: FAIL

$ cat output/t1.t 
syntax error at t1.t line 1, at EOF
Execution of t1.t aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Now we can understand what is going wrong with our `t1.t` test.

Still I did not find an option/a solution to see that output from `prove` like at **@ikegami** example:
[image]